# How to control power of MAAS nodes via the CLI?

Tags: power-management, maas

From the CLI help entry, maas doesn't seem to have the ability to turn off power to individual nodes. I can't use the web interface because reasons.

I've identified the correct system_id of the node and can query the power parameters:

```
$ maas imran node power-parameters w3qbqc
{
    "power_pass": "thiswasapassword",
    "power_user": "maas",
    "power_address": "10.1.1.2",
    "power_driver": "LAN_2_0",
    "mac_address": ""
}
```

But there seems to be no way to control the power:

```
root@cluster00:~# maas imran node -h
usage: /usr/bin/maas imran node [-h] COMMAND ...

Manage an individual Node.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit

drill down:
  COMMAND
    read            Read a specific Node.
    delete          Delete a specific Node.
    details         Obtain various system details.
    power-parameters
                    Obtain power parameters.

The Node is identified by its system_id.
```

Answer (score 0):

`maas imran machine power-on w3qbqc` is what you want.

A node is an instance to provide image/service. A machine is an instance to take care of physical (bare metal) items (like power on/off and the other bare metal configuration). So nodes have only "power parameters" to show, which is a part of the current service status, and machines control the power on/off, which is a part of the bare metal setup.

What maas does is to abstract the operation of the node, focusing on the power on/off action (namely start/stop the node) so you don't need to take care of the power parameters if you have setup them already at the very beginning.

Answer (score -2):

There is a way to change the power parameters.
Try using:

> `maas imran machine update w3qbqc power_type=<power_type> power_parameters_power_address="<new power address>" power_parameters_power_user="<user>" power_parameters_power_password="<password>" power_parameters_<any power parameter here>=<power parameter value>`

`power_parameters_<power parameter>` depends on your power_type.